# Quiero descomprimir un fichero ZIP con contraseña y no me acuerdo de ella. Lo quiero descomprimir con John Ripper

Tags: zip, winrar

Tengo un fichero ZIP antiguo comprimido con contraseña, de la cual ya no la recuerdo. En él tengo dentro pues unos 20 documentos. Quiero sacar la contraseña con John Ripper y cuando ejecuto el comando (**run>zip2john nombre.zip**) para averiguar el hash, me aparece un hash enorme, del cual no puedo leer el principio de la pantalla y al final dice lo siguiente:

Resultado:

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*$/pkzip2$::Docu01.zip:HPIM0533.JPG, HPIM0535.JPG, HPIM0534.JPG:Docu01.zip

**NOTE: It is assumed that all files in each archive have the same password.
If that is not the case, the hash may be uncrackable. To avoid this, use
option -o to pick a file at a time.**

¿Alguien sabría como tengo que hacerlo? ¿tengo que utilizar el parámetro -o y como se utilizaría?

Por cierto lo estoy haciendo desde windows. y estoy utilizando la versión "john-1.9.0-jumbo-1-win64".

Gracias.

Comment: ya intentaste correrlo con `--show`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que ejecutar los siguientes comandos:

```bash
zip2john nombre.zip > nombre.hash
john nombre.hash
```

si deseas pasar alguna wordlist en especial lo realizas de esta manera:

```bash
john --wordlist=wordlist.txt nombre.hash
```

**Nota:** En caso de que tu wordlist este con otro directorio diferente al de nombre.hash tendrás que especificar así:

```bash
john --wordlist=C:\ruta\a\wordlist.txt nombre.hash
```